# Writing to a File in Android (New Scoped Storage)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-external-storage, file-storage

I have written the below-mentioned code to write a PDF file with ResponseBody.

```
 private fun writeResponseBodyToDisk(body: ResponseBody): Boolean {
    return try {
       val fName = "TestFile.pdf"
        val directoryName =
           context
                .getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

        val actualFileName = File(directoryName, fName)
        if(!actualFileName.exists()){
            actualFileName.createNewFile()
        }

        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
            var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
            inputStream = body.byteStream()
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(actualFileName)
            while (true) {
                val read: Int = inputStream.read(fileReader)
                if (read == -1) {
                    break
                }
                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()
            }
            ToastUtils.showShort("File Downloaded")
            outputStream.flush()
            true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            ToastUtils.showShort("WRITE Catch Block==>"+e.message)
            false
        } finally {
            setShowLoading(false)
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close()
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        ToastUtils.showShort("PDF Catch Block==>"+e.message)
        false
    }
}
```

Whenever the above-mentioned code is executed, I always get the exception in Catch.

**Exception**: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xyz.abc.staging/files/Download/TestFile.pdf: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

I am testing it on Android 11 and I have to build this code for Android 6 and above. However, it is working well on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but since you have not said anything about it, does the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xyz.abc.staging/files/Download/TestFile.pdf directory exist on your device? If so, then remove it and try to run your code again. In general your code should work on Android 11. As a side note, you should check the return value from actualFileName.createNewFile(). Also, can you specify what versions of Android are on those other "some devices" where your code works? I am also assuming that you have tested your ToastUtils and the exception is not thrown from there.